# PostgreSQL query optimization when joining a large table to a small table

Tags: postgresql, optimization, sql-execution-plan

Hi I have the following query to make a report from certain date to the begin of the DB.

```sql
explain (analyze, buffers)
select
    (
        select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(v)))
        from (
                select cl.fkp as fkpueblo,
                    cr.pk::varchar(255),
                    (
                        (
                            cr.creado at TIME zone 'Mexico/General' at TIME zone 'UTC'
                        )::date || ' ' || cl.n || ' ' || cl.paterno || ' ' || cl.materno
                    ) as nombre,
                    cr.montocredito,
                    (
                        cr.creado at TIME zone 'Mexico/General' at TIME zone 'UTC'
                    )::date as creado,
                    (
                        select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(u)))
                        from (
                                select h.pk::varchar(255),
                                    h.concepto as nombre,
                                    h.monto,
                                    h.tipo,
                                    (
                                        h.fecha at TIME zone 'Mexico/General' at TIME zone 'UTC'
                                    )::date as fecha
                                from historial h
                                where h.fkcr = cr.pk
                                    and (
                                        h.fecha at TIME zone 'Mexico/General' at TIME zone 'UTC'
                                    )::date < '2022-07-30'
                                    and h.del = 0
                                    and (
                                        select COUNT(h.pk)
                                        from historial h
                                        where h.fkcr = cr.pk
                                            and h.tipo in (3, 6, 9, 10)
                                            and h.del = 0
                                    ) > 10
                                order by h.fkcr,
                                    h.fecha asc
                            ) as u
                    ) as historiales
                from credito cr,
                    cliente cl
                where cr.del = 0
                    and cr.fkc = cl.pk
                    and cl.fkp = p.pk
                    and (
                        cr.creado at TIME zone 'Mexico/General' at TIME zone 'UTC'
                    )::date < '2022-07-30'
                    and (
                        cr.fecha_cierre is null
                        or (
                            cr.fecha_cierre is not null
                            and cr.fecha_cierre >= '2022-07-23'
                        )
                    )
                order by cr.creado asc
            ) as v
    ) as creditos,
    (
        select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(u)))
        from (
                select csm.tipo_monto
                from corte_semanal cs,
                    corte_semanal_montos csm,
                    corte_pueblo_padre pp
                where pp.del = 0
                    and p.pk = pp.fkpueblo
                    and pp.fksupervisor = cs.fksupervisor
                    and cs.pk = csm.fkcorte_semanal
                    and csm.del = 0
                    and cs.del = 0
                    and p.del = 0
                    and (
                        cs.fecha_corte at TIME zone 'Mexico/General' at TIME zone 'UTC'
                    )::date >= '2022-07-23'
                    and (
                        cs.fecha_corte at TIME zone 'Mexico/General' at TIME zone 'UTC'
                    )::date < '2022-07-30'
                    and csm.tipo_monto < 4
                order by csm.tipo desc,
                    csm.tipo_monto asc,
                    csm.concepto asc
            ) as u
    ) as montos
from pueblo p,
    ruta r
where p.del = 0
    and p.fkr = r.pk
order by r.ruta,
    p.pueblo asc
```

And this is the planning

### Sorry, I had to place it on Pastebin since it was more than the body limit of the post.

https://pastebin.com/d627nxkJ

Using DBeaver I exported the planning as a graph image

[image: Planning]

As you can see, this is an expensive query to run so I went a try to optimize it.

When I started a few days ago, I noticed that some nodes had an `External Merge on Disk plan` so I checked the `work_mem` and it was on default, `4MB` and so I changed it to `1GB` but it didn't affect significantly to the overall execution.

I used this to change the work_mem

```
ALTER ROLE <user> SET work_mem TO '1GB';
```

---

### Indexes

In this query there are two major tables:

historial and corte_semanal_montos on which historial has 1,882,074 rows and corte_semanal_montos 106,705 but at the end of the query there are about 1,084 rows due to aggregations.

publo has 1,141 rows and rutas only 33 rows.

Historial is the biggest table on the query by a large amount to I tried to make some indexes on where columns.

```sql
create index idx_del_zero on historial(del) where del = 0;
create index idx_tipo on historial(tipo) where tipo in (3, 6, 9, 10);
create index idx_fkcr_fecha on historial(fkcr, fecha);
CREATE INDEX idx_expr ON historial ((fecha at TIME zone 'Mexico/General' at TIME zone 'UTC'));

create index idx_del_zero_p on historial(del) where del = 0;
create index idx_del_zero_csm on corte_semanal_montos(del) where del = 0;
```

But again, it didn't affect significantly to the overall execution time.

Right now I don't know how can I proceed on making this query faster.

My postgreSQL version is

```
PostgreSQL 9.5.23 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to remove all code not directly relevant and absolutely required to describe your problem; your giant query cannot be the smallest possible query that demonstrates the problem - please make it so.

Comment: Any particular reason to use the [outdated Postgres 9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)?

Comment: Try to reduce the query to the minimum that exhibits the problem. Nobody wants to dig through that wad of SQL, particularly for a performance question on a desupported version of PostgreSQL and without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: Not really, it is just an old database. Would there be any improvement over upgrading postgresql?